# Cordova build android Error: cordovalib:compiledebug:java

Tags: cordova

When I am running:

cordova build android

`:Cordovalib:compileDebugJava FAILED`

Error being returned:

> Execution failed for task `':cordovalib:compileDebugJava'`.
>   Cannot find system Java compiler

I am pretty sure that I have set my `JAVA_HOME` Variable right. Why could cause this error?

Answer (score 0):

I'm also a newbie, but i recently install and run cordova successfully after a big struggle. And this is one of the problem i had during the run. so come to the point,

many stuffs may responsible for this.

- You need to install `ant` and not only JAVA, `ANT_HOME, ANDROID_HOME` are also need to be properly configured environment variables when run cordova.

or

- heard that I'm not sure about your version of cordova. always try to keep it upto date version. use `npm update -g cordova`.

or

- Removing android from project using `cordova platform remove android`.
  And then adding android again `cordova platform add android`
  may also fix your problem.

knock all the door. something will open for you.

Goodluck buddy

Answer (score 0):

I have been facing this problem after updating my cordova version to 5.1.1 and the problem has been fixed by

1. Removing some plugins like the older version of inappbrowser plugin,
   GAnalytics plugin etc from my project and
2. Removing android from project using `cordova platform remove android`.
   And then adding android again `cordova platform add android`